# Ruby Equivalent of Python "_"

Tags: python, ruby, irb, python-idle

In Python, you can use the `_` field to grab the last computed value. That's really useful in IDLE. Does Ruby have an equivalent for IRB?

An example from Python:

```
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> _
4
>>> "Me " + "You"
'Me You'
>>> _
'Me You'
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really sorry I posted this. I was dead-set that _ didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

_ isn't working?

```
host:~ user$ irb
irb(main):001:0> s = "test"
=> "test"
irb(main):002:0> puts _
test
=> nil
```

Answer (score 5):

In IRB you can use `_` as well.